# SAP CAP: PATCH call for OData.Draft.enabled Entity returns 404

Tags: sapui5, sap-cap, sap-business-application-studio, sap-business-technology-platform

For my SAP CAP Bookstore app, I am trying to make a PATCH call from my Workflow App via Service Task (PATCH).

This worked fine. Now we changed the target app to `@OData.Draft.Enabled` which adds an appendix to the target URL. Through that the PATCH call does not work any more as you can see in the screenshots.

Before `OData.Draft.Enabled` → field "title" changed successfully

[image]

Including `OData.Draft.Enabled` - the GET Request in that scenario worked fine and responded the desired data.

[image]

Does anyone know about this?

I would much appreciate any thoughts/hints for a potential solution.